# How to run Websphere Liberty in debug mode inside docker container?

Tags: java, docker, remote-debugging, websphere-liberty

I added this to my Dockerfile and the changes reflect on "docker inspect"

`CMD ["/opt/ibm/docker/docker-server", "debug", "defaultServer"]`

The server logs indicate that the server has stopped and the ports (http only, not 7777) are unbound), but the java process is still running, thus not letting the container die.

I can go inside the container and start the server with this command and everything works fine

`/opt/ibm/docker/docker-server run defaultServer`

What am I doing wrong?

**Server logs :**

---

A CWWKE0001I: The server defaultServer has been launched.

I CWWKE0002I: The kernel started after 2.253 seconds

I CWWKF0007I: Feature update started.

I CWWKF0008I: Feature update completed in
0.250 seconds.

A CWWKF0036I: The server defaultServer has finished gathering a list of required features.

***A CWWKE0036I: The server defaultServer stopped after 2.804 seconds.***

Comment: Did you try running
    /opt/ibm/docker/docker-server debug defaultServer

?

Comment: @ewhoch the port 7777 was still bound, so running that command from within the container failed. But I can run server in normal mode and both (normal and debug) modes combine (!!) to make it work.

Comment: is something else in your container using 7777? You can configure the port that debug binds to using the WLP_DEBUG_ADDRESS env var. Though rereading, it sounds like your issue is that you think the server is fully shutdown but something is still waiting and holding that port open. In that case did you try a ps -aux | grep java to see if any processes are still running? Apologies if i misunderstood at first.